# Grab Dynamically Appended Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsbin.com/kunawoho/1/edit

Working example - http://jsbin.com/vuwaxuqi/1/edit

I'm working on an experimental web designer and I'm trying to grab already added values of css selectors. The fiddle I made generates two buttons and is suppose to clone the input [type=text]. The first is an X meaning close. The second is the text of the value. However I keep getting `[object Object]` returning from the dynamically cloned input [type=text]. (No errors are showing up in console either)

I want to click the button and grab the dynamically added value from before and display it in the selector. (I know I can grab this from the button's text, but cause I'm working wit 30+ values in my app it makes more since to stick with what I'm using and grab from that in a closed container. That way everything is grouped and easier to manage).

Not sure why it's not cloning.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addvalz").on('click', function() {
    // Adds value
    $(".val-nester").append("<div class='holddezvalz'><button class='deldizval'>x</button><button class='grabdezvalz'>"+ $(".inputval").val() +"</button>"+ $(".inputval").clone() +"</div>");

    // Can't add same value twice. Replace?
    var $cssselbtn = $(".val-nester > .holddezvalz button:contains(" + $(".inputval").val() + ")");
    if($cssselbtn.length > 1) {
      var x = window.confirm("Selector already exists. Want to replace it?");
      if (x) {
        $cssselbtn.first().parent().remove();
      } else {
        $cssselbtn.last().parent().remove();
        return false;
      }
    }

    // Delete a value
    $(".deldizval").on('click', function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });


  });
});
```

Comment: Instead of [object object] you want values of width, height and padding?

Comment: atm I'm just focused on the selector. If I can get that cloned width height and padding won't be a problem, but it must be contained in the div the other elements are added in. (In this case div.holddezvalz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on [@Regent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24798359/2685386), just split up the `append` line:

```
   $(".val-nester").append("<div class='holddezvalz'><button class='deldizval'>x</button><button class='grabdezvalz'>"+ $(".inputval").val() +"</button></div>");
   $(".val-nester > div.hoddezvalz").append($(".inputval").clone());
```

Or, a little more readable:

```
$(".val-nester").append($("<div class='holddezvalz'>")
     .append("<button class='deldizval'>x</button>")
     .append("<button class='grabdezvalz'>"+ $(".inputval").val() +"</button>")
     .append($(".inputval").clone())
);
```

---

Also, you should sanitize `input.val()` before you append it to the DOM. Replace `input.val()` with something like

```
.append( ... + $("<p>").text( $(".inputval").val() ).text() + ... );
```

Then, in the selector, you should surround it with quotes and escape quotes inside it

```
":contains('" + $(".inputval").val().replace("'", "\\'") + "')"
```

Comment: I noticed you didn't add any closing or self closing tags (<div />) Not sure how it closes itself, but good to know. BTW it's also adding the previously added selector. = http://jsfiddle.net/UuVKL/

Comment: jQuery adds closing tags for you; the angle brackets `<>` just tell it to create a new element rather than select one from the DOM

Comment: As for it adding the second one: that's because `".inputval"` selects all inputs with that class. Add something like `$(".inputval:first").clone()` to get just the first one

Answer (score 1):

You placed `$(".inputval").clone()` into the string, so it was converted to string.

Try this instead:

```
$(".val-nester").append($(".inputval").clone());
```

**EDIT**: about whole adding:

```
var addDiv = $("<div class='holddezvalz'><button class='deldizval'>x</button><button class='grabdezvalz'>" + $(".inputval").val() + "</button></div>");
$(addDiv).append($(".inputval").clone());
$(".val-nester").append(addDiv);
```

Comment: It's also adding the previously added selector. = http://jsfiddle.net/UuVKL/ how would this be fixed?

Comment: @mikethedj4 yes, I saw this problem. Actually you can add something unique to them (`id`, or `data-value`, or whatever else) or take only first or last one. I'll try to do something with this now

Comment: I ended up doing `.valz2add .inputval:first-of-type` and it works fine. I forgot how `.inputval` selects all classes with that name.